# Sort a dict according to both key and value at the same time

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict that looks like this:

```
{0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 5}
```

That is, both the keys and values integers.

I need to sort this dict in this way:

- By the value first, ascending;
- by the key, if the values ties, descending.

All I know is that python's sorted() function supports a parameter called "key" but it seems that it just allows to have either key or value at once.

What can I do to achieve?

FYI, the result should be like:

```
{2: 2, 0: 2, 3: 2, 1: 4, 4: 5}
```

Comment: Not all dictionaries can be sorted at all.

Comment: Dictionaries can't really be sorted, but since 3.6 they preserve insertion ordering : https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/13892264

Comment: Why does it need to look that way? The dictionary displays itself as best suited to its structure.

Comment: @PeterWood: Because?

Comment: @ScottHunter If they need to iterate over the dictionary in a particular order then they can sort the keys first. It's an odd request to display the dictionary structure for anything other than debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not an easy way to say "this value, ascending, then this one, descending". However, if you negate each of a list of integers, then sort it, then that's the same as sorting it in reverse.

This defines a sorting key which is a tuple:

- The first value is each dict item's value.
- The second value is each dict item's key, but negated.

```
d = {0: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 1: 4, 4: 5}


def sort_key(item):
    key, value = item
    return value, -key


print(sorted(d.items(), key=sort_key))
```

This outputs:

```
[(3, 2), (2, 2), (0, 2), (1, 4), (4, 5)]
```

See? The items are grouped by value, and in the event of a tie, by key in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries can't really be sorted, but since 3.6 they preserve insertion ordering, so you can create a new dictionary from the sorted tuple items of the previous dictionary.

To get what you want, you have to do this twice - once by key, then by value.
This works because python's `sorted` is guaranteed to be "stable" - if two items are identical then it won't change them, so the second value sort will preserve the initial key sort if two values match.

```py
input_dictionary = {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 5}
sorted_by_key = dict(sorted(input_dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True))
sorted_by_both = dict(sorted(sorted_by_key.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
print(sorted_by_both)
```

[Demo](https://replit.com/@LukeStorry/68025495)

Answer (score 1):

[How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

```
data = {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 5}
sorted_data = dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item:item[1]))
print(sorted_data)
```

output

```
{0: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 1: 4, 4: 5}
```

Comment: OP asked to sort by value *then* key.